# Site-packages error in CKAN connected to ckanext-showcase

Tags: python, ckan

I have installed a CKAN Instance and I have installed the ckanext-showcase module.
Although the installation didn't raise any errors and I was able to add a few showcases when some of my users that I had set as showcase administrators started adding showcases the module has stopped working.

```
The page {portal.url/showcase} can't be viewed unless I am connected as system administrator. When a user or even a showcase user tries to enter the page get's an internal server error.

From that point on when I am trying to create a new system administrator from console with the paster command (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/getting-started.html#create-admin-user) I get the bellow message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 703, in
main()
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 683, in main
paths_in_sys = addsitepackages(paths_in_sys)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 282, in addsitepackages
addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 204, in addsitedir
addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 173, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in
KeyError: 'ckanext'
```

Because I don't have the ability to install the CKAN again right now, is there any suggestions on how I to fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: After looking to my server error logs I found that the error wasn't caused by the plugin ckanext-showcase but from the module ckanext-datarequests. The first part of my problem was connected to a server error coming at a 401 Unauthorized exception not being handled at version 1.0.2 of the plugin. As soon as I upgraded to the latest version 1.0.3 the error was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking to my server error logs I found that the error wasn't caused by the plugin ckanext-showcase but from the module ckanext-datarequests.
The first part of my problem was connected to a server error coming at a 401 Unauthorized exception not being handled at version 1.0.2 of the plugin. As soon as I upgraded to the latest version 1.0.3 the error was fixed.